# C# Trying to return indexes on duplicated items inside a list, but the loop keeps returning the index of only the first duplicate

Tags: c#, list, indexing, foreach, duplicates

Whenever I run this, I want to have the index's of the list items to be displayed. However when i have the loop search for one of the items on the list, it will give me multiple indexes, but it's only the index of the item that comes first in the list. So if there were 2 instances of that list item, it would give me the indices of 1 and 1(Example).

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress enter to display team list with duplications");
        Console.ReadLine();
        List<string> teamList = new List<string>();
        teamList.Add("cubs");
        teamList.Add("red sox");
        teamList.Add("yankees");
        teamList.Add("cubs");
        teamList.Add("yankees");
        teamList.Add("yankees");

        foreach (string teams in teamList)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(teams);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Select an item in the list: ");
        string teamSelected = Console.ReadLine();
        List<int> indexList = new List<int>();


        if (teamList.Contains(teamSelected))
        {
            foreach (string teams in teamList)
            {
                if (teams == teamSelected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(teamList.IndexOf(teams));


                }
            }
        }
        else { Console.WriteLine("That is not an option!"); }
```

Comment: You can also try these weirdos:  `var DistinctResult = teamList.Distinct().ToList();` `var DuplicateResultsIndexes = teamList.Select((s, idx) => teamList.FindIndex(idx, ss => ss == "yankees")).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking it to give you the index of `teams` using `.IndexOf()`.  Even if there are multiple indices with the same value, e.g. `teamList[0]` has the same value as `teamList[3]`, `.IndexOf()` will always return the first index found.

To remedy this, you should use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop like so:

```
for(int index = 0; index < teamList.Count; index++)
    if(teamList[i] == teamSelected)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

`List.Count` gets the amount of items stored in `List`.

Comment: Alright thank you! This really helped and I now understand what was causing the problem!

Comment: @Bkwiat If the post solved your problem, click the gray tick on the left side to mark it as the answer.